# DataTables - Expand Child details without using Ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm working on a page that uses jquery DataTables (version 1.10). The TableData source is currently being sent as just an HTML table on the rendered page, and works perfect. However I want to be able to expand the rows to show detailed information.

Very much like the example [Here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

However, the site I'm working with currently does not have any sort of web services set up on it yet, so I won't be able to make ajax calls to get the expanded information like the example uses.

Is there a way I can supply all of the necessary information for the parent child relationship on a fully rendered page?

Can I somehow nest the table data to get this, or tell DataTables to make every other table row a child of the one above it?

I posted this same question on the datatables forums: [Question](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20903/parent-child-expand-details-without-using-ajax#latest)

Comment: If you can have all the required data in the table to start with then it is easily possible.  Do you have full control over the html, or is being generated dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I have full control over the rendered HTML, which is generated dynamically.

Comment: `<input id="column-01-row-01" type="hidden" value="your-data"/>`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can store the data for the child row in a `data` attribute of the parent row and change the `format` method from the example accordingly. Something like

In your HTML:

```
<tr data-child-name="test1" data-child-value="10">
    <td>ParentRow</td>
    <td>No. 1</td>
</tr>
```

In the `click` handler (line 50 from the example):

```
row.child(format(tr.data('child-name'), tr.data('child-value'))).show();
```

And as `format` method something like:

```
function format (name, value) {
    return '<div>Name: ' + name + '<br />Value: ' + value + '</div>';
}
```

Comment: That actually works pretty well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But how can I pass more data? For example, I want to show additional information (up to 20 individual information "pieces") of my doctrine entity in a twig template. Is JSON_Encode of the whole entity the right approach?

Comment: It is worth testing. Another idea would be to only add one id as data property to the row and store all data for the child rows in an js object or array.

Comment: +1 Works great.  I don't even both passing individual extracted tr.data elements to my format() function; I just pass the whole tr, and then I do the extraction from tr.data('foo') and so forth inside that format function, since it's more convenient (to me) to have the per-field naming right there with the per-field formatting, and since adding or removing another data field means I only have to edit two places (the HTML tr and the format function) and not an additional third place (the click handler).

Comment: @Raidri Could you pelase hav e look at [Cannot list details data in jQuery Datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998706/cannot-list-details-data-in-jquery-datatable)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Thank you for this. FYI your click handler line is missing a right parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

While technically this example isn't exactly using AJAX, it is essentially exactly the same concept. You are still forced to add rows using a format function, whether than format function builds the HTML getting values from AJAX or hard-coded into your data-attributes, what is the difference.

As far as I know, there is no way to have the child rows inserted into your HTML from the start and just have the expand controls just SHOW the already existing HTML for the child rows, not build the child row HTML, insert it into the DOM and show it.

Comment: Well that's just bad. :(

Answer (score 0):

Whoever ends up here. I know this question has already an accepted answer, but it didn't work for me.
What worked for me:
I used exact example from here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html
Only thing I changed is

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt", <-- this line I changed
```

To

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "data": <%-JSON.stringify(data.table)%>,
```

I used ejs so I sent data from server-side and in html I could use <%= data %>, which had the table, but in html script I had to use data.table like this:

```
<%-JSON.stringify(data.table)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with format function is, if your div is a complex html, then creating it by concatenating strings is cumbersome.

If you look at the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()), you will find that row.child() function also accepts Jquery node objects as input !!

So you can create your div element the usual way

```
<div class="hidden" id="hidden-info">
    Name: test1 <br/>
    Value: 10
</div>
```

Hide it using Jquery this way

```
$(".hidden").hide()
```

And then when you need to create the row child. Search for the div. Clone it. And pass it as a Jquery node object to row.Child() function.

```
row.child($("#hidden-info").clone().removeClass("hidden")).show();
```

No more headache of string concatenations and formatting