# How to add a custom view more details button using DataTables?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do you do a custom view more details button in DataTables? Yes I know DataTables already has a view more details button but I would like to have a custom designed one.

I want when I click on a custom view more button the child rows are revealed.

[image: demonstration]

This is the code I have been trying to use, with **'.table-toggle'** as the class name to active it to whatever i apply this classname to.

Here are the scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.20/r-2.2.3/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.20/r-2.2.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="never">ID</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th class="none">Date</th>
            <th class="desktop">Time</th>
            <th class="desktop">Balance </th>
            <th class="none">Payment Type</th>
            <th class="none">Note</th>
            <th class="desktop">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table-toggle">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>     
                  <h5>Charles Smith</h5>
                   <span>Lending</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                -$500.00
            </td>
            <td>02-January-2020</td>
            <td></i> 11:01 am </td>
            <td>$67,256.00</td>
            <td>Cash</td>
            <td>Collected and deposited</td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table-toggle">View More</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>Edit</span>           
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>Delete</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
<script>
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('.table tbody').on('click', '.table-toggle', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var table = $('.table').DataTable();
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });

</script>
```

This is my HTML code on the button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table-toggle">View More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
  <script>
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('.table').on('click', '.table-toggle', function () {
       var table = $('.table').DataTable();

       var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

       var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        } 

    }); 

    /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d[0]+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d[1]+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

</script>
```

Okay i got the code to work. If you put the class **'.table-toggle'** on any object it will work. if you put the button in the table row, and you click on the button it will fire twice. One fire for the `tr` and the other for the `td`. So keep that in mind.

```
<tr class=".table-toggle">
  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table-toggle">View More</a></td> 
</tr>
```

If you want to format what is shown in the child table you can use the link or reference.
The Child Details example uses the `format()` function as a way to build the HTMl that will display your child rows. You can use any valid HTML you would like and display only the portions of the row data you want. https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

This is how your format code will look replace the above line:

```
  // Open this row
    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
```

This link shows a good way of doing the formatting:
[DataTables - Expand Child details without using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566754/datatables-expand-child-details-without-using-ajax)